# What are all the R.I.P.D. comics currently available?

Tags: comics, r.i.p.d

I'm trying to assess if it's feasible for me to read all RIPD (Rest in Peace Department) comics before I see the movie.

So far, unless I'm hugely mistaken, there appear only two publications: A single RIPD comic book that the movie is based on, and a 4-issue prequel called "City of the Damned".

Is that correct and exaustive? (as of 10/2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you get the single prequel for the movie "City of the Damned" and the R.I.P.D.: Volume 1 (graphic novel) which includes the four R.I.P.D comics (first published in 1999) you will have everything written on the series at the moment.

A reprint of the four comics as a trade paperback was reissued in March 2003.